# Database Model returning empty data to Laravel blade apparently, What am I missing?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting an empty table when I return the DB data to blade laravel.

Controller.php

```
public function showreport($id) 
{   
    $data = Cases::find($id);
    return view('report',['reports'=>$data]);
}
```

Report.blade

```
@foreach($reports as $report)       
    <tr>
        <td>{{$report['id']}}</td>
        <td>{{$report['first_name']}} {{$report['last_name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$report['cnic']}}</td>
        <td>{{$report['area_code']}} {{$report['phone']}}</td>
        <td>{{$report['first_def']}} {{$report['last_def']}}</td>
        <td>{{$report['case_type']}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('history/report/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\CaseController::class, 'showreport'])->name('user')->middleware('auth');
```

Cannot seem to troubleshoot the issue. It echoes the $data variable fine, but it is not displaying that row in the table.

Comment: you should get an error like `Trying to access array offset on value of type bool` in this. does it show any error??

Comment: Cases::find($id) should return a single Cases object, not a collection which is iterate-able.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon no it doesn't. Just an empty table.

Comment: Instead of `find($id)` try `where('id', $id)->get()`

Comment: If I remember correctly, find method returned object or collection of objects, not an array Try to get data in a cycle like from an object 
$report->id e.t.c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggestion by IGP worked.

In the controller I changed $data = Cases::find($id) to $data=Cases::where('id', $id)->get()

Comment: why would you have more than 1 record with the same 'id'?

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` method is useful for getting single record from table using its primary ID value. So it just returns a single record not an array. If you want to get an array of records, you can use:

```php
$data = Cases::query()->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Which it might be logically wrong. Because while you always need a single record, why did you use a table at all?

Comment: For the user, each case carries a single set of details. But for the admin, he can retrieve multiple users' cases and their details at once.